# C# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: startIndex cannot be larger than length of string. (Parameter 'startIndex')

Tags: c#, text

Unhandled exception:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: startIndex cannot be larger than
> length of string. (Parameter 'startIndex')    at
> System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)    at
> Film_Libary.Registration.Login() in /Users/elliot/Documents/Film
> Libary Software/Film-Libary/Film-Libary/Registration.cs:line 75

This error occurs when im trying to validate the user infomation of username and password from the text file to what they inputted

```
public void Login()
        {

            string fileName = @"/Users/elliot/Documents/Film Libary Software/Film-Libary/Film-Libary/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/UserInfo.txt";

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter your username");
                string line;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    int indexOfDelimiter = line.IndexOf('|');
                    string usernameFromFile = line.Substring(0, indexOfDelimiter);
                    string passwordFromFile = line.Substring(indexOfDelimiter + 1, line.Length - (indexOfDelimiter + 1));
                   

                    if (usernameFromFile.Equals(Username))
                    {
                        if (passwordFromFile.Equals(Password))
                        {
                            {
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: The content of the file is overwritten because of `using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(filePath)) ;`, checking out the [`File.CreateText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.createtext?view=net-6.0) documentation it clearly states that "If the file already exists, its contents are overwritten." also, the `File.WriteAllText` does the same (overwrite if the file exists), instead use [`File.AppendAllText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalltext?view=net-6.0)

Comment: @MindSwipe Hello, Thanks alot. Ive got a few problems still and it would be great if i could get some help on that aswell. First one is that i want the username input and password input on the same line in the text file seperated with a split line so i am able to validate the infomation in the login method through indexing or something like that, and then each time i restart the application the next username input appends itself to the previous one with no spaces or not even different line. Im really confused on how to implement a fix to this? Cheers

Comment: It's quite easy to put username and password in the text file, you can simply do `string toWrite = username + "|" + password` or any other delimiter between username and password. I recommend separating entries by a new line, so you'd user 1 and a password for them on line 1, and user 2 and a password for them on line 2 and so forth. You can look up CSV and structure your text file like that. For reading back in, you need some kind of structure, else it's gonna be incredibly hard if not even impossible to properly read in username and password combos for different users

Comment: Please post a sample of what the text file looks like.

Comment: @JuanR Hello, Elliot|Benten67 Fred|Payne Toby|Hadden . That is what it looks like. Ive made it so there is a space between each pair of username and password

Comment: Can passwords contain spaces or pipes?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure how your code is organized, and what should happen when a user logs in etc, but here is some sample code.

The main program asks the use for input, which then determines if the user wants to log in or do something else (like in you original post).

If the user chooses to log in, the login method will check if the entered username and password is correct. The txt file used in this example is on the format you provided with whitespaces separating each entry.
example:
username1|password1 username2|password2 username3|password3

```
    static string fileName = "C:\\usernames\\username_pass.txt";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int options = 0;
        int numberOfOptions = 3;    //Number of options the user can choose from
        bool running = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Film Library. Press 1 to log in 2  for Registering");

        //User chooses what he wants to do
        //WHile loop will not exit before valid input is detected
        while (running)
        {
            try
            {
                options = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                if (options < numberOfOptions) running = false;
                else Console.WriteLine("Input a valid choice");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please input a number");
            }
        }

        //Choose option based on input from user
        if (options == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter username and password");
            Console.Write("Username: ");
            string username = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Password: ");
            string password = Console.ReadLine();

            if (login(username, password)) Console.WriteLine(username + " Succesfully logged in");
            else if (!login(username, password)) Console.WriteLine("Login failed");
        }
        else if (options == 2)
        {
            //Do something else
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Here is the login method which returns true if login is verified. I have tested it with a couple of usernames and passwords and it seems to work fine

```
 //Returns true if login is verified
    //Returns false if login is incorrect
    public static bool login(string username, string password)
    {


        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
        {
            //Splits the text from txt file into string array using whitespace as delimiter
            // txt in format: username1|password1 username2|password2 etc....
            string[] users = reader.ReadToEnd().Split(null);

            //Loop through array of strings, split username and password.
            //If correct username is detected, check if password is correct
            for (int i = 0; i < users.Length; i++)
            {
                int indexOfDelimiter = users[i].IndexOf('|');
                string usernameFromFile = users[i].Substring(0, indexOfDelimiter);
                string passwordFromFile = users[i].Substring(indexOfDelimiter + 1, users[i].Length - (indexOfDelimiter + 1));

                if(username.Equals(usernameFromFile))
                {
                    if(password.Equals(passwordFromFile))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else if(!password.Equals(passwordFromFile))
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for helping may i ask how would i make it so in the login Method that the user writes the username and password then it checks with the block of code. Also username doesnt seem to be found and password aswell even though they are in the same class? Thanks

Comment: @ElliotFreebairn I have now edited my answer with a working login method. Hope this helps. Alternatively you should post a more complete example of what you are trying to achieve since it is easier to help if you post a more complete description.

Comment: Yes i will defintely do next time i post, Also thanks alot for helping. Have a good night!

Comment: @Ive got a quick question, is it bad practice or good practice to have both the login and registration methods in a seperate classes to declutter the Main method and make it easier to navigate between different functions. Cheers